# Multiple conditions regex JavaScript split

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'd like to split a string if:

- It doesn't starts with a `quatre` or a `soixante` AND
- It doesn't ends with a `dix` or a `vingt`

For example:

```
'deux-cent-quatre-vingt-trois'.split(/**/);
> ['deux', 'cent', 'quatre-vingt', 'trois' ]
```

I've had a few tries and failures, for example:

```
'deux-cent-quatre-vingt-dix-trois'
          .split(/^(?![quatre|soixante]-[dix|vingt])(\w*)-(\w*)/);
> [ '', 'deux', 'cent', '-quatre-vingt-trois' ]
```

or:

```
'deux-cent-quatre-vingt-dix-trois'.split(/(?!quatre|soixante)-(?!vingt|dix)/);
> [ 'deux' 'cent', 'quatre-vingt', 'trois' ]
```

which works, but this does not:

```
'cent-vingt'.split(/(?!quatre|soixante)-(?!vingt|dix)/);
> [ 'cent-vingt' ]
```

I know using a matcher or a find would be so easy, but it would be great to do it in a single split...

Comment: I assume you want && between your points..

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't understand what you meant at first.

Comment: Hmm... It seems like javascript doesn't support lookbehinds.. Are you trying to separate all the french numbers from zero to quatre-vingt-dix-neuf + cent?

Comment: Yes, more or less. It's for a module I've been working on, [readint](https://github.com/nmussy/readint). It's a written number parser. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible to make the translating process easier. I only do one split, to identify and mark number tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var text = "deux-cent-quatre-vingt-trois";

console.log(text.split(/(?:^|-)(quatre-vingt(?:-dix|s$)?|soixante-dix|[^-]+)/));
```

The idea is to add a capturing group whose content is added to the split list.

The capturing group contains at first particular cases and after the most general, described with `[^-]+` *(all that is not a `-`)*

Notice: since `quatre-vingt` is written with a `s` when it is not followed by a number, i added `s$` as a possibility.

Comment: suppose one needs to prevent the _'-'_ followed by _'quatre'_ alone from getting removed in that sentence, what is the regex for that? If possible please let me know, I am trying to understand the answer.

Comment: Either you capture quatre-vingt (or quatre-vingts, or quatre-vingt-dix), or you capture soixante-dix, or you capture whatever you find until an hyphen. That last case is what separates the elements, by capturing everything but the trailing hyphen.